# jQuery inArray() not working? It's not finding strings that I'm sure are in the array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have an Array object that looks like this:

```
var wordList = new Array();
$.get('words.txt', function(data){
    wordList = data.split('\n');
});
```

When I do this:

`return jQuery.inArray(word, wordList)!==-1;`

Using a word that I //know// is in the array, it'll still return false. It might be that the array is too large (it contains 173,139 strings) - is this it? In this case, should I give up on using an array, or is there a different way to go about searching the array?

I checked the type of the word and the elements in the array - both are string according to JavaScript's `typeof`.

What's odd is that I've used inArray with the same words and a different array, and it works just fine - the difference is the way the arrays are generated (one is through the same input I get `word` from, and one is by splitting lines in a .txt file).

Also, when I try to call the element explicitly by its index, it shows up, so I'm sure the array is loading in. I'm using high index numbers too; calling wordList[173138] doesn't make the response time slow in any way.

Why isn't inArray() working here?

Comment: You can't use teh value of `wordList` outside of the `$.get()` callback because of the asynchronous nature of ajax.... what ever you want to do with `wordList` has to be done in the success handler

Comment: Oh, sorry, I tried looking for a duplicate question before I posted this - that's embarrassing.

Comment: Wait... I'm using `wordList[173178]` outside the `$.get()` callback. I can use `wordList[index]` but can't use `inArray()` on wordList? Or am I missing something again?

Comment: Can you show us your `wordList data`?

Comment: Sure! I'm using the ENABLE word list, found here: https://code.google.com/p/dotnetperls-controls/downloads/detail?name=enable1.txt

Comment: You tried it like, `var wordsList=['abc','test',1];alert('test index='+$.inArray('test',wordsList)+'\n'+'1 index='+$.inArray(1,wordsList)+'\n'+'x index='+$.inArray('x',wordsList));` [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rohankumar1524/BLrsC/)

Comment: That's an example of inArray working properly, but when I use it on my array, it returns -1 even if I give it a word that I checked the list for. For example, if I did `inArray('biology', wordList)!==-1`, it would return false.

Comment: Its working, you may have some other problem, I used some words from your text file and it works for me, see [another demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rohankumar1524/BLrsC/1/)

Comment: For future Googlers: after much exasperation, I ended up fixing the problem by doing `data.split('\r\n')` instead of `data.split('\n')`. It's some different kind of newline or something, relating to Windows.

Comment: @Aranv, add it as an answer to the question. That way it will get the full attention it needs. After a time delay, you can even mark it as the answer to make it really clear :)

Comment: will do. Thank you for helping me help others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I put this in the comments originally, but was told to make it an answer - this should make it easier to find. For anyone having trouble looping through arrays like this, check the way you're splitting your array if it's split by newlines - my array was causing some trouble because I was using `data.split('\n')` where I should've been using `data.split('\r\n')`. After fixing that, everything was fine.